# Charge distribution on co-planar capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, resource-recommendations, capacitance

I'm looking for books on a complete analysis of co-planar capacitors and their electric fields at DC, such as between narrow and wide traces on a PCB. Any suggestions?

I think there's a some research literature that might help, but its an expensive gamble to access.

Comment: see, e.g.,https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0471224758.ch2